# How do I make variables in a Main accessible to other classes?

Tags: java

For example I have a MovieDatabase class that contains a list of Movie objects. In my main code, I initialize all the objects in the MovieDatabase. However I wish to call this MovieDatabase in another class to access the library. How would I do this?

Do I add in get methods in my main code and return it? Or is there another way (eg. changing the list of objects to protected/public?)

Thanks!

Code's supposed to be 3 seperate classes, Main, MovieDatabase & Movie.

An instance of movieDatabase is initialized in Main. Upon construction, it calls loadMovieList() and populates the list from a text file. However I wish to call the same instantiation of movieDatabase from another class in order to access the movies, so that I do not have to repeat the loading.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MovieDatabase movieDatabase = new MovieDatabase();
}

public class MovieDatabase {
ArrayList<Movie>movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
String fileAddress = "D:/Users/Mine/School/Java/CZ2002_Assignment/src/MovieDatabase/movieDatabase.txt";

public MovieDatabase()
{
    numOfMovie=0;
    loadMovieList();
}

public int getNumOfMovie() {
    return numOfMovie;
}

public void addMovieToList(Movie movie) {
    movieList.add(movie);
    numOfMovie++;
}

public Movie selMovieByID(int movieID) {
    int index=-1;
    for (Movie m : movieList) {
            index++;   
            if (m.getMovieID() == movieID)
                break;
    }
    return selMovieByIndex(index);
}


public Movie selMovieByIndex(int index) {
    return movieList.get(index);
}

public void loadMovieList()
{
    //loads through text file
    addMovieToList(new Movie(tempMovie));
    System.out.println("Movie Database loaded");
}

public class Movie{
private int movieID;
private String movieName;
private int movieDuration;  //in minutes;
private String movieRating; //G; PG; PG13; NC16; M18; R21;
private boolean has3D;
private boolean status; 
}
```

Comment: Are the variables static or instance?

Comment: Can you please post some code ? That would make helping a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class that depends on a NameLibrary, you should inject it via the constructor or a set method.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, its difficult to assess what issues you truly have without any code to show us.
However you mention main method, as in 
public static void main(String args[]){};

this main method is designed specifically to run the application, your compiler needs that specific method, it is not designed to be used as an accessor method 
e.g.

```
public int getValue(){
return value;}
```

this is not the only reason you can't access the main method variable. main doesn't have a return type (due to the use of void) plus the idea of SCOPE (each method has a scope, any method that contains a variable can see that variable, but nothing outside of it can directly see it without a return type) you use scope to limit what can be accessed or what cannot be accessed outside of the methods or classes (thats why class variables usually will have private, in order to limit accessibility)

Answer (score 0):

Create a getter-method which returns the list inside your `NameLibrary`. if your other class extends from `NameLibrary` you can call this getter-method with the object reference to your `NameLibrary` class.

Comment: Does this mean I will have multiple instances of nameLibrary though?

Like if I need it once in the main, I create it. And if I need it in another class, I create a new one? And these would be 2 seperate instances so whatever I update inside one class won't be reflected on the other?

Comment: Yes you create one in a other class and one in main. You have two seperate instances which arent getting affected on changes from a other instance

Answer (score 0):

If you want `int x` to be accessible from other classes, you write:

```
public class myClass{
    public int x = 0;
}
```

To access it from other classes, you simply write:

```
myClass.x ... (do something)
```